User-defined implicit cast to generic is not used
I have a class that encapsulates a generic class T, and it has an implicit operator to convert the encapsulating class to T.
However, that conversion is only ever used if I cast explicitly in the calling code.
I haven't found any rules that seem to apply.
This is .Net 8.0, C# 12.
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

        var r = new Result<Contact>(new Contact() { FullName = "Otto" });
        Console.WriteLine(r.Value.FullName); // This works, no surprise
        Console.WriteLine(r.FullName); // Squiggly under FullName. CS1061: 'Result<Contact>' does not contain a definition for 'FullName' and no accessible extension method... 
        Console.WriteLine(((Contact)r).FullName); // Explicit cast works
    }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string FullName { get; set; } = "";
}

public class Result<T>
{
    public T Value { get; }
    public int Index { get; }

    public Result(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Index = 0;
    }

    public Result(T value, int index)
    {
        Value = value;
        Index = index;
    }

    public static implicit operator T(Result<T> result)
    {
        return result.Value;
    }
}



Try again with Contact r = .... If  you don't r is still a Result<T> and cannot be used interchangeably as if it were a T. What you can do is pass it as T or assign it to a T-typed variable. But that's (about) it.

That's not how implicit conversion works. No conversions are performed in a member access. To do something like this, you'd need to implement IDynamicMetaObjectProvider or inherit from ExpandoObject/DynamicObject, which is not trivial at all.

I guess this would only work if there was an overload of Console.WriteLine that expects a Contact.

What I really wanted to do was to return a class that expanded T with one property. That would be easy if the DTO class was fixed. However, I am not allowed to inherit from a template class, like public class Result<T> : T

A variable can only have one type. In your case r is Result<Contact>. You cannot use it as both Result<Contact and Contact for simultaneous access to members of both types.
What you did allows you to pass r where Contact is expected without needing to explicitly cast.
var r = new Result<Contact>(new Contact() { FullName = "Otto" });
Console.WriteLine(r.Value.FullName); //Otto
// implicit cast works because the parameter is of type Contact
// which Result<Contact> impicitly converts to
Action<Contact> action = c => Console.WriteLine(c.FullName);
action(r); // Otto


Excellent. Thanks.
